# Expand a clist from l3prop keys

Tags: comma-separated-list, l3keys, l3prop

I have a key that takes a comma-separated list as its value, with entries coming from the keys of a property list. I would like the "default" (no-value-given) to apply the key to every key of the property list. I can't figure out how to convert the property keys to an expanded clist that can be passed to `\clist_map_inline:nn`. Here's a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_mymodule_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \g_mymodule_prop
  { A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4 }
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  { 
    print .code:n =
     {
       \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
         { \prop_item:Nn \g_mymodule_prop { ##1 } \par }
     },
    print .default:n = {  } % What to put here?
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\SetKeys[mymodule]{print={A,C}}

\SetKeys[mymodule]{print}

\end{document}
```

Something like

```
print .default:n = { \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_mymodule_prop { ##1, } }
```

doesn't work because `\clist_map_inline:nn` sees it as a single-item clist, and of course there's no property key with that name. I've also tried using `on` and `en` variants of `\clist_map_inline:nn` but `\prop_map_inline:Nn` is not expandable (I think) so that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to do this the way I'm approaching it? If not, is there a way to provide completely separate code for the "default" version of a key that does not rely on the initially provided `.code:n`?

Comment: you could get a list of keys but (by design) the order is not defined, so you can't really get `{A,B,C,D}`  which is I think the default you want, unless you save that when you create the prop list.

Comment: that is you could use `\prop_map_inline:Nn` to re-construct a clist but you will possibly get a permutation of `{A,B,C,D}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The order is not important. I'd like to re-construct a clist but I can't figure out how to do this within the confines of `.default:n`

Comment: I think you'd have to do it first, before the setting or in .initial so you have a local clist variable to use as default, but before that I need to eat:-) (or someone else may answer)

Comment: So you want the result to be as if you'd said `A,B,C,D` but without specifying `A,B,C,D` as the default?

Comment: If you set up the clist first, you could use `.default:V = <name of clist var>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I was going map over the property list to make a clist to use as in the non default case, but since you are mapping over the prop list you may as well use the values directly rather than collecting the keys:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_mymodule_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \g_mymodule_prop
  { A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4 }
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  { 
    print .code:n =
     {
%\showtokens{#1}
       \clist_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
         { \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_mymodule_prop {##2\par} }
         { \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } {\prop_item:Nn \g_mymodule_prop { ##1 } \par }}
     },
   % print .default:n = {  } % What to put here?
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\SetKeys[mymodule]{print={A,C}}

\bigskip

\SetKeys[mymodule]{print}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Though I can imagine a use-case where one wants different behavior from `print` and `print={}`

Comment: @mbert you could use `.default=B` then `print` would give the value of `B` and `print={}` would give them all

Comment: Yes, but I meant something more like a handler `.no_value_code:` where the code for a key with no value given is not necessarily equivalent to giving the key a specific, default value. I would guess this is not suggested because it unties the semantic connection between `key` and `key=value`.

Comment: @mbert not provided by default but you could use `.default=$$!!@@` some unique value and then test for that (rather than empty) in the `.code` bit.

Comment: Perhaps that is a good use for `key .default:n = \q_no_value` then test with `\quark_if_no_value:nTF`

Comment: much more idiomatic expl3 than my suggestion, yes:-) @mbert

Comment: @mbert (shameless advertisement:) or you use a keyval package that has the distinction between keys with a value and without a value built in: `expkv`

Comment: @Skillmon is that a version of `keyval` package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but one without bugs and misbehaviours :P